# Coalesce with inner select and count not working

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

Why do I get this result with this query?

```
{"num_added":null,"num_completed":"0","num_liked":"0","following":"1","followers":"0","success":1}
```

"num_added" should be 0 instead of null.

```
try {
        $stmt = $conn->prepare("
        SELECT

        COALESCE((SELECT COUNT(ID) FROM USERS_BUCKETS WHERE USERS_BUCKETS.USERID = USERS.ID),0) AS ADDED,
        COALESCE((SELECT SUM(CASE WHEN USERS_BUCKETS.STATUS='Completed' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) FROM USERS_BUCKETS WHERE USERS_BUCKETS.USERID = USERS.ID),0) AS DONE,
        COALESCE((SELECT COUNT(ID) FROM USERS_LIKES WHERE USERS_LIKES.USERID = USERS.ID),0) AS NUM_LIKES,
        COALESCE((SELECT COUNT(ID) FROM FOLLOW WHERE FOLLOW.USER_ID=USERS.ID),0) AS FOLLOWING,
        COALESCE((SELECT COUNT(ID) FROM FOLLOW WHERE FOLLOW.FOLLOW_ID=USERS.ID),0) AS FOLLOWERS

        FROM USERS 
        WHERE USERS.ID=?");

        $stmt -> execute(array($userid));
            while ($row = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) {

                $response["num_added"]= $row['ADDED'];
                $response["num_completed"]= $row['DONE'];
                $response["num_liked"]= $row['NUM_LIKES'];
                $response["following"]= $row['FOLLOWING'];
                $response["followers"]= $row['FOLLOWERS'];

            }
            $response["success"] = 1;
        } catch(PDOException $e) {
        echo 'ERROR: ' . $e->getMessage();
        $response["success"] = 0;
    }
```

Comment: There is no field named 'ADDED' in your query.

Comment: That's true, I fixed it, but that doesn't change the question that why do I get null instead of 0

Comment: why do you have coalesce for each of these? just run it with the COUNT() or SUM() as those will return a 0 if there are no matching rows... also this query is really bad you should just join the tables.

Comment: @JohnRuddell - COUNT() will return 0 if there are no matching rows.  SUM() will return NULL.

Comment: @Tom yes but in this instance with the CASE the OP is putting in a 0

Comment: @erdomester - If you had no field named ADDED in your query perhaps that was why num_added returned NULL.  The COUNT() function even without a COALESCE will return a 0 and never a NULL.

Comment: @JohnRuddell - It will still return a NULL if there are no records.

Comment: @Tom not if the OP followed the rest of my advice with joins... If you join the tables and then run a query with a case it would return a 0.

Comment: *"but that doesn't change the question..* Well, it kinda does. If the field doesn't exist, then `0` won't be the result. The modified query should give `0` though.